# How to get a German Umweltzone sticker while on the road?

Tags: germany, automobiles

I'm driving a Czech rental car into Germany and would like to have an Umweltzone sticker so that I can drive into cities. Where can I get one while on the road and what documents are needed?

The car itself is a brand new Skoda that certainly meets the environmental requirements. It just needs the sticker to certify this.

Comment: It [*seems*](http://www.umweltbundesamt.de/themen/luft/luftschadstoffe/feinstaub/umweltzonen-in-deutschland#textpart-3) that similar Czech stickers are also valid in the German Umweltzones. Maybe your rental car has already one of those.

Comment: @Glorfindel Google Translate of that page tells me that "due to delays in the Czech Republic, however, no Czech plaques are issued and German plaques are not yet recognized in the Czech Republic".

Comment: Ah, I only read the first sentence of that paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The stickers can be ordered online, for example [here](https://www.umwelt-plakette.de/en/store.html)`*`. You need to present the vehicle's registration while ordering, and have these documents with you for inspection by local police in case you encounter a traffic stop.

Edit: As for possibilities to get these stickers offline, any car repair shop / garage, DEKRA and TÜV outpost is allowed to sell these, and I'd bet any KFZ-Zulassungsstelle has them, too. Maybe ring up a repair shop along your route to see if they are willing to part with one of these, especially regarding the place of registration of your rental. Bonus: It'll be much cheaper than ordering online (more like 2 to 10 EUR instead of 30+ EUR).

`*` This is not an endorsement, I am not affiliated with that shop. It is merely the first result on Google for an appropriate search. Being a German native, I have never had to use such a shop, thus I do not have any experience regarding its quality of service.

Comment: Are there any offline places where you can get it done?

Comment: @JonathanReez sure, I've updated my answer. Sorry - I had been under the impression that you wanted to solve this before even starting your trip :)